executing external scripts, do I need compile?
When executing external scripts
Executing External Scripts - Tips and Tricks - Blender Python API
I know I am meant to use:
filename = "/full/path/to/myscript.py"
exec(compile(open(filename).read(), filename, 'exec'))

But I accidentally used:
filename = "/full/path/to/myscript.py"
exec(open(filename).read())

It works!
Is there any good reason not to use the shorter form?
What is the purpose of the missing compile, filename and 'exec'?

From the Python docs on the compile() function.

This function raises SyntaxError if the compiled source is invalid, and
ValueError if the source contains null bytes.

Whenever you use the open() function to open a file, you're accessing that data while the script is running, but not explicitly closing it off. This means if your script stops running in the middle for some reason, you can potentially leave that file "half-open" which can cause corrupted data and other problems. The compile part can give you a warning which you can check for, and then use that to tell your script to close the file if there's any issues.
It should be mentioned though, that the exact syntax from the Blender docs is the quick-and-dirty python way that will technically work. But a better way might be something like this.

filename = "/full/path/to/myscript.py"

# using this syntax automatically handles opening/closing the file,
# avoiding that aforementioned issue. 

with open(filename, 'r') as my_script:
    loaded = my_script.read()

# Then once the file is loaded in, compile and execute

exec(compile(loaded, filename, 'exec'))





Excellent, thank you. And if I want to pass arguments to my script, is this (below) correct?
Of course I would retrieve any arguments in the called script.
filename = "/full/path/to/myscript.py"
arg1 = 15
exec(compile(loaded, filename, 'exec'), {'arg1': arg1})

Yes, I just confirmed that that does work. That dictionary is a replacement for the locals argument. You would access them in the target script by getting them from the locals() dict.

Exactly. You can pass globals and locals, separately and in the correct order. I don't know how to enter formatted code into a comment...

You can't do full formatted code in comments, other than using the backticks to change the font/highlighting. Glad you figured it out though.
